# How to take the bake texture completely off the mesh

Tags: texturing

I seen a post similar to this, but to clarify my question.

being blunt I really want this baked texture removed from a mesh leaving it fully blank if it's possible to do.

alternatives will also be considered if it can't be done.

Comment: you can simply unplug the Image Texture from the Principled BSDF in the Shader Editor?

Comment: thanks for the help!!